# ECMAScript-262 implementation in C?

Tags: javascript, c, interpreter

> Possible duplicate: [Tiny javascript implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384762/tiny-javascript-implementation)

I have searched around for a C implementation of Javascript, but I couldn't find one. I need this for an ultra-portable application that will run on platforms without a C++ compiler.

Here are my requirements:

- ANSI C (C89 compatible if possible)
- Minimal dependencies
- Embeddable (not stand-alone)
- Open Source (GPL v2 compatible)

I don't care about speed, but correctness is an issue. I would prefer for it to support ECMAScript-262 v5, but v3 is good enough for now.

Does something like this exist? If not, are there any implementations that would be relatively simple to port?

[DMDScript](https://github.com/DigitalMars/DMDScript) is the simplest that I've found, so I may end up porting that. Apparently there is no [reference implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507848/does-a-real-ecmascript-implementation-exist-or-is-it-just-a-spec), so this may be the best way to go.

Note:

I also found [tiny-js](http://code.google.com/p/tiny-js/), which is meant to be small and simple, but it doesn't seem to be standards compliant. It **is** actively developed it seems...

Comment: What about a C++ to C compiler? That one should be findable.

Comment: oh my gosh, it sounds like major pain in the ass, but I actually hope you find what you're seeking for. Please update this question if so :)

Comment: @jAndy not "update", "self-answer".

Comment: @JanDvorak: nit-picker alert !

Comment: Is "freeware" a requirement? If not, given time and money, I am willing to code you one `:-)`

Comment: @JanDvorak Hmm... I guess that could work, but getting this to work cross platform with dependencies will be a royal pain if I have to debug something generated. And yes, free is a requirement (it's for an open source project I'm committing to).

Comment: @JanDvorak: The old [cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) C++-to-C translator is unlikely to be suitable (development was abandoned in 1993). [Comeau C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeau_C/C%2B%2B) might do the job, but it's not free. Don't expect the C generated by any C++-to-C translator to be legible or maintainable.

Comment: What CPU? Google's V8 compiles JS into machine code for a few CPUs.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze "ultraportable" as in "whatever C compiles to"

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze x86, but it needs to be an interpreter because the ecmascript will be dynamic (user supplied). Platform in this case means Amiga/RISC OS/etc...

Comment: @tjameson Not having the code until runtime is expected  by a javascript compiler. Knowing the target instruction set architecture does help performance.

Comment: @JanDvorak I understand that, but V8 is written in C++, which doesn't meet my requirements. I assumed that pre-compiling the JS before-hand was implied.

Comment: @tjameson V8 compiles at runtime, not at com--- what?

Comment: I still agree the fact V8 is coded in C++ kinda rules it out.

Comment: @JanDvorak Do you by chance know where I can get a copy of Comeau's compiler? The [website](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) appears to be down...

Comment: @tjameson Never encountered it. You'll have to google a bit.

Comment: Perhaps an old version of SpiderMonkey would be in pure C.

Comment: @JanDvorak If you can find an old version where that's the case, put it as an answer. I'd certainly upvote that =)

Comment: I intend to investigate.

Comment: Strange, it seems that SM 1.8 is, in fact, C. Are you willing to verify? http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js-1.8.0-rc1.tar.gz

Comment: @JanDvorak Throw that in as an answer. It looks like C! The readme even mentions that it is C.

Comment: actually in C world Lua is the king of embeddable dynamic languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SpiderMonkey wiki claims it is C/C++, however, from looking at the source package, it seems to be pure C actually.

The official download link is http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js-1.8.0-rc1.tar.gz

If that doesn't turn out to be pure C, try the older versions. Their FTP (http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/) currently hosts spidermonkey 1.8.5 down to 1.4, and Rhino 1.7 down to 1.4.

[The documentation for Spidermonkey API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference) seems good as well.

Answer (score 3):

Spidermonkey 1.8.0 RC1 and the previous releases are in C. You can use that.

They introduced C++ in their latest release as of 11 Feb 2013 in 1.8.5 release

Comment: Thanks for the more specific info. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried http://www.duktape.org/? I've been looking around for the same for a while, and this one just got me a wink. I'll test it and see how it goes, but to start, looks promising